# App not working with 3g connection but works fine on wifi

Tags: ios, swift, 3g, alamofire

Adhoc deployed app on a device, the app runs fine with wifi, but does not work with 3g connection. Any idea what i'm missing?

Din't get much help from google.

And also the app installed does not show in the Use Mobile Data For : list

Code :

```
    //To handle time out issue with 3g

    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60

    // Mark using Alamofire to do the downloads

    self.alamofireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration:configuration)
    self.alamofireManager!.request(.GET, jsonUrl).responseJSON(){
        (_, _, JSON, _) in
        println("printing json :\(JSON)")
        if JSON != nil {

              let imageInfos = (JSON!.valueForKey("image") as [NSDictionary]).map {
                ImageInfo(id: $0["id"] as String, url: $0["url"] as String)
            }

           self.tableData.addObjectsFromArray(imageInfos)
 }
```

Error log:

I get a

```
(Error Domain = NSURLErrorDomain Code = -1004 )
```

no matter how much i increase the timeoutInterval. Tried both with Resource and Request

Forgot to mention that the server was a Raspberry Pi, and i could not access the server outside the LAN so that was causing the problem. Thanks for the help. timeout was very helpful in handling server faults.

Comment: Are you use web service for get data form server side and which library are you use for get data from server side side may be problem is time out request?

Comment: using Alamofire to handle the webservice communication.

Comment: Stupid question, but do you have enough data left from your provider?

Comment: was not so stupid till i realised the reason for the problem was a stupid ignorance. not asking a question, just updating the question so other don't make the same mistake.

Comment: @mozado have you solve you problem? then please tell i am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

there wan't be any issue with app working on wifi or 3G. the only problem with `request timeout`. the issue related to internet bandwidth.

Comment: request time out from client or server side?

Comment: one thing i don't understand here, if client or server gets timeout. when i switch from 3g to wifi immediately, the app works. Time out cause if speed of the connection?

Comment: not time out means how long your request can be responsive. in wifi connection, you will get larger internet bandwidth compare to 3G so you request can be received response in small time compare to 3G network.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code for change request time out may be help to you.

```
var alamofireManager : Alamofire.Manager?

func getCallToServer(){
  let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
  configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10 // seconds

  self.alamofireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
  self.alamofireManager!.request(.GET, "http://example.com/")
    .response { (request, response, data, error) in

    }
}
```

Comment: appreciate the help. but the above code does not solve my problem. Even increased the timoutIntervalForResource to 60.

Comment: Have you solve your problem @mozado if yes can you please share code here so we can learn new things.

Comment: No did not solve my the problem, i'l update the post with the code. These problem is not very common? because i can't find much help on stack or google.